# R: strange unwanted output from readline

Tags: r

I am trying to get input from stdin in R. 
here is my code

```
fil <- file("stdin")
open(fil)
fn <- readline(fil)
fn <- strsplit(fn, split = ' ')
f <- fn[[1]][1]
n <- fn[[1]][2]
write(n, stdout())
close(fil)
```

when I run this code

```
> fil <- fil("stdin")
> open(fil)
> fn <- readline(fil)
4
```

I get this unnecessary number `4` out of nowhere. sometimes it's 3 sometimes its 4. where is it coming from?

Comment: yeah I realized that and changed it in my code. it's not causing the error though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readline()` is supposed to get input from the user in *interactive mode*. The argument of `readline` is a prompt:

```
> n = readline("enter num: ")
enter num: 3
> n
[1] "3"
```

The line

```
fn <- readline(fil)
```

is interpreting `fil` as a prompt. The number that you are seeing (3 or 4) is thus the *file handle* assigned to `stdin` by the `open()` function, which makes for a pretty cryptic prompt.

I think that (assuming that you are trying to pipe in data from `stdin` in a batch setting) you need to use `readlines()` instead. Type `?readlines` for information. On the other hand, if you are writing a program to get input interactively from the keyboard, skip that part about opening `stdin` as a file and just use `readline(<prompt of your choice>)`. The function `readline()` is already hooked up with `stdin`.